# Modifiying JS to meet new HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am have a small script written in JS for a form. The script looks like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Test for placeholder support
    $.support.placeholder = (function(){
        var i = document.createElement('input');
        return 'placeholder' in i;
    })();

    // Hide labels by default if placeholders are supported
    if($.support.placeholder) {
        $('.form-label').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('js-hide-label');
        });  

        // Code for adding/removing classes here
        $('.form-group').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function(e){
            console.log(e);
            // Cache our selectors
            var $this = $(this),
                $parent = $this.parent().find("label");

            if (e.type == 'keyup') {
                if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                    $parent.addClass('js-hide-label'); 
                } else {
                    $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label');   
                }                     
            } 
            else if (e.type == 'blur') {
                if( $this.val() == '' ) {
                    $parent.addClass('js-hide-label');
                } 
                else {
                    $parent.removeClass('js-hide-label').addClass('js-unhighlight-label');
                }
            } 
            else if (e.type == 'focus') {
                if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
                    $parent.removeClass('js-unhighlight-label');
                }
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

and this is my form in HTML:

```
          <form id="contact-form" class="form" action="#" method="POST" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"  required>
              </div>                           
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="email">Your Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"  required>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="message">Message</label>
                  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message..."  required></textarea>                                 
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-start-order">Send Message</button>
              </div>
          </form>
```

This works well, as can be seen here: https://codepen.io/stephanrusu/pen/QwKLJX

I have modified my form to have a `<span></span>` tags around the input/textarea. In the JS this requires looking for `input and textfield` inside the span which has class name `wpcf7-form-control-wrap`. So my HTML looks like this now:

```
          <form id="contact-form" class="form" action="#" method="POST" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
                  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap fullname">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"  required>
                  </span>
              </div>                           
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="email">Your Email</label>
                  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"  required>
                  </span>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
                  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap subject">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                  </span>
              </div>                            
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="message">Message</label>
                  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap message">
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message..."  required></textarea>                                 
                  </span>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap fullname">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-start-order">Send Message</button>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </form>
```

So my questions is how can the JS be modified to work with the following form. All that is added is  around the inputs and textareas.

Many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: it's working with your new html, but you must change css styles

Comment: Where is it working with new HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, just change the line:

```
$parent = $this.parent().find("label");
```

to

```
$parent = $this.closest(".form-group").find("label");
```

After update of form, `$(this).parent()` refers to `<span>` instead of `<label>`. `$this.closest(".form-group").find("label")` will refer correctly to `label` elements.